# Linear gradient and background size adding this cool effect, can any body explain

Tags: css, linear-gradients, background-position, background-size

I am sorry if it is dumb question, but this code is driving me crazy, i strip it down, was thinking i will be able to understand, but after doing that and investing 2-4 hours now i am confused about the things which i thought i knew.
This below code adding this cool effect when i over, it seems like background is appear from the bottom and goes to the top,
Only think i knew it has to some thing with background image, linear gradient, background size, and background-position

Please have look and try to take me out of my misery.

```css
li {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 50%, #a2d39c 50%, #a2d39c 95%, #7cc576 95%);
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}

li:hover {
  background-position: bottom center;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've annotated your styles below to hopefully explain what is happening.

```
li {
    // You're creating a background gradient, where the first 50% is transparent, the next 45% is #a2d39c and the last 5% is #7cc576
    background-image: 
        linear-gradient(to bottom, 
        transparent 50%, 
        #a2d39c 50%, #a2d39c 95%, #7cc576 95%);

    // The background size is twice the height of your element. Therefore with the 50% transparency and initial position, you're not going to see anything
    background-size: 100% 200%;

    // This will nicely transition between CSS property values when they change
    transition: all .25s ease;
}
li:hover {
    // When you hover over your list item, you're changing the position so that the bottom of the background is visible. This causes the 50% transparent portion of the background to disappear, and the coloured portion to slide into view
    background-position: bottom center;}
}
```

**Background Position**

If you check out the CSS specs for [background-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-position), you'll see that the default value is `0% 0%`, which is basically `top left`.

Your CSS code does not specify an initial background position and so it will default to `top left`. Keep this in mind.

Your background gradient is defined `to bottom`, so from `top -> bottom`. The first 50% is `transparent` (invisible). The second 50% is comprised of two different colours.

Then consider that your background gradient is twice the height of your element. This is specified by the `background-size: 100% 200%` (100% width, 200% height). The background can be larger than the element to which it is applied, and any overflow will be hidden.

So initially when you're showing only the top half of your background gradient, what are you going to see? Only the `transparent` portion.

When you then override the `background-position` on hover, you're saying to now show the `bottom center` portion. Seeing as how your background matches the full width of your element, the `center` horizontal value doesn't change anything. But the `bottom` vertical setting does. It now means that the second 50% is displayed.

Does that help?

Comment: I am accepting your solution, as it does make sense, but i am still confuse about the background-position, can you explain bit more thanks

Comment: @user2860957 - I've updated my answer. Does that help clarify? If not, can you explain a little more what you don't understand? The positioning, how the gradient is created, etc?

Comment: @fuber thanks for the help nice man, i was reading it and keep on getting confuse, after that i search how background-size work, if i have googled it before posting a comment, you did not have to waste your time editing the perfect solution, if it's possible for you add this line as well, background-size can be bigger than than element, but it will only show you the element size background, hope you understand what i am trying, as any nutter like come here, it might help him to, understand what happening here. Thanks and i am upvoting as well you answer two question for me thanks

Comment: I've added that line (in slightly different words).